# What is the volume of the region that is within a distance r outside of the surface of an n-dimensional hypersphere of radius R?

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, spherical-geometry, solid-of-revolution

Suppose you have an n-dimensional ball of radius R living within a d-dimensional space. Imagine the region in d-dimensional space consisting of all points that are a distance r outside the surface of that n-ball. What is the volume of this region for any n, d, R and r?

In other words, what is the volume of the Minkowski sum of the sets N and D, where N is the n-ball of radius R and D is the d-ball of radius r?

So take the special case of d=3 dimensions to begin with. For n=1 we have a cylinder of height 2R and cross-section with radius r plus two hemispheres on either end of a flat line (the 1-d sphere). The combined volume of the hemispheres is just $2*(1/2)*(4/3)*\pi$$r^{3}$. For n=2 the region desired is the cylinder with a cross-sectional area of radius R times the height 2*r plus the outer half of a donut. To find this semi-donut volume I understand we can use the second centroid theorem of Pappus-Guldin by using the centroid of the semicircle of radius r, which is $\frac{4r}{3\pi}$. Then we find the volume of the desired semi-donut region by taking the area of the semicircle of radius r and 'sweeping' it around the circumference of the circle of radius R + $\frac{4r}{3\pi}$. This gives the formula $2\pi(R+\frac{4r}{3\pi})*\frac{1}{2}\pi*r^{2}$.

For n=3 you could obviously find the desired volume by taking the difference in volume of the sphere of radius R+r and the sphere of radius R, but I want a method that can generalise to a hypersphere of any dimension n in a space of any dimension d. Can the approach using the Pappus-Guldin theorem be generalised? Alternatively, I'm thinking a solution using calculus must be possible, but I don't know how to find it. So is there a neat formula for this?

Thanks :)

Comment: It seems you are looking for the volume of the [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) of an $n$-sphere and a $d$-ball, except for $n=d$ where you want to exclude the interior of the sphere. Don't know whether this view is of any use, but perhaps this alternate formulation can turn up some useful pointers.

Comment: Thanks! I've had a look at the wikipedia page for Minkowski sums and it looks like a useful formulation of the problem. I forgot to mention in my post that this is only part of the full problem that I'm working on, but I've edited my question now to be more precise about what I want. I want the total d-dimensional volume of the Minkowski sum of the set of points N and D, where N is the n-ball of radius R and D is the d-ball of radius r.